# Do Static classes with static methods keep Entity Framework from opening too many connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, static-methods

I started on a new project in which mvc 3 with EF 4.1 is used.  the Service layer is hosted as WCF and then it has a project for Entity Framework.  The Service layer that was put up is using static classes with static methods to talk to Entity Framework.

Now I fine static to be not a "good idea"  is is harder to unit test and not allowing polymorphism etc...   My team leads says "reason for static is so it doesn't open up a bunch of connections to Entity Framework"  that seems not correct to me...

Here is a sample class that gets the data from EF with Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using PM.DAL;
using PM.DomainModel;
using PM.DomainModel.Staffing;
using PM.Service.DataMapper;
using PM.DomainModel.Enums;

namespace PM.Service
{
public static class Staffing
{

    public static List<HabMatrixSchedule> GetDefaultHabMatrixSchedule()
    {
        var query = new List<HabMatrixSchedule>();
        using (var ctx = new DDDPROGRAM_MONITORING_DBEntities())
        {
                query = (from ad in ctx.lkptblDEFAULT_RESOURCE_ALLOCATION_DETAIL
                         join hl in ctx.lkptblHOUR_LOOKUP on ad.HOUR_LOOKUP_ID
                         equals hl.HOUR_LOOKUP_ID
                         select new HabMatrixSchedule()
                         {
                             DEFAULT_RESOURCE_ALLOCATION_DETAIL_ID = ad.DEFAULT_RESOURCE_ALLOCATION_DETAIL_ID,
                             HOUR_LOOKUP_ID = hl.HOUR_LOOKUP_ID,
                             WEEKDAY_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID = ad.WEEKDAY_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID,
                             HOUR_START = hl.HOUR_START,
                             HOUR_END = hl.HOUR_END,
                             Resource_Count = ad.RESOURCE_COUNT,
                             CurrentWeekDayTime = new WeekDayTime(ad.WEEKDAY_CATEGORY_VALUE_ID, hl.HOUR_LOOKUP_ID)                                 
                         }).ToList();

            return query;
        }


    }


}

}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, EF is NOT thread safe. I believe it does open up multiple connections, or rather it attempts to. I've run into issues before using multi-threading and EF. Try using the UnitOfWork approach.

Comment: So does the above code seem like it should not use static method?

Comment: Word to the wise: "connection pooling". Ok, that's _two_ words.

Comment: @JohnSaunders   Please explain how connection pooling has to do with static methods.  thx

Comment: Static or instance, no matter how many "connections" you think you're opening, connection pooling means you're opening far fewer - maybe only one.

Comment: Ok, so regardless of whether static is used, it comes down to the way in which the connections are opened and closed, how many etc...,  how can I do connection pooling with MANY methods like the above ones being called?

Comment: Most likely, you are already doing that. It's the default.

Answer (score 0):

The code certainly **can** be called in parallel and apart from that, I see no reason why it should limit load (in a way that a non-static function wouldn't). (Whether it will execute in parallel without errors depends on shared data. Maybe there even is something with a mutex, but still I fail to see in how far static-ness changes the situation.)

Comment: Well, go about and ask, out of honest curiosity. I don't know whether there are circumstances that your sample does not reflect, but if there aren't, I am pretty confident in claiming that the desired effect is not achieved by the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article relating to Unit Of Work pattern, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx. This is the way I had to build my application when executing code in parallel.

Comment: I'm familiar with UOW, but that pattern is just a pattern typically used with a repository pattern,  explain how a pattern prevents the issue of open connections?

Comment: EF 4.1 I'm going to say that your EDMX designer file has a partial file in which ObjectContext is implemented.  SO, what is known about ObjectContext is that it internally implements several patterns including Identity Map and Unit of Work.

Answer (score 0):

This static method you showed creates new context every time it is called. So it doesn't change anything if you remove static from method definition.

You should not create static context unless you create one user desktop app. For web application you should create one context per one web request.